# How to publish in a group using app token?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app token which has permission to publish in a group.  And a user token but he doesn't have a permission to publish in the group nor he is an admin.

How can he publish in the group using the app token?

Note from documentation:
App access token can be used for a person who has already granted user_photos and publish_to_groups permissions for creating a group album using your app

My code so far:

```
from facebook import GraphAPI
graph = GraphAPI(access_token='my_access_token')
message = '''
the message
'''
graph.put_object('my_group_id', "feed", message=message)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code!

Comment: I added my code . But what I use now is user token. But the user doesn't have a publish to group permission. However I have an app token with permission to publish in group.

Comment: What you quoted from the docs appears to be about creating new albums, not necessarily for posting to the normal group feed?